# IE8 will not load certain sites

Tags: windows-7, browser, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue with our corporate build whereby a select few websites (unfortunately I cannot name them) are causing problems because they simply will not load. There are no error messages we simply get the "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" and the Diagnose Connection Problems button. The More information is generic and provides no help.

Here is some other information you may need:

- These are corporate machines on a corporate network - Windows 7 64bit
- IE 8 - we cannot upgrade to IE 9 although it suffers the same issue
- Other browsers do work - thus proving network / proxy stuff is fine
- All settings have been reset to no avail
- We have even copied all of the advanced settings from a machine that is on a separate off network build (which works) to no avail
- Tried with no addons
- Tried with site added to trusted zones / intranet etc and nothing.

I know this is not virus related and it is something specific to our build or an update but I am hoping someone here can provide me some tools or methods to use to identify and resolve the issue

Thanks

Comment: Can you try Firefox in order to see if their prehaps is a filtering problem?

Comment: Also, try the issue on a completely different computer (or more than 1) that also has IE8.  That should rule out a configuration problem that only exists on a certain computer.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that ie8 loads these pages fine off-site, but not on site. So I would think either the version of ie8 you are running needs to be updated, or there is a proxy issue.

If the websites are hosted on your network you will need to add the domain name to the proxy ignore list. In ie8 it can be found in.

`Tools->Internet Options->Connections->LAN settings->Advanced->Exceptions`

Without knowing much more about the websites you are having issues with that's all I can think of sorry.

Good Luck

Comment: Sorry I was confusing with my language there. I mean that a non corporate (actually corporate for a different place) machine works fine. But the build we have on these machines simply does not work. The website is an internet site so not a local one and windows xp with ie 7 (on other machines obviously) work fine proving the proxy is good. THanks